# Why is seeing vote breakdowns such a high-rep privilege?

Tags: discussion

I just got the see vote-breakdowns privilege, and I can't understand why it's such a high-rep privilege. You can't really do anything wrong with that info, so why is it so high in the privilege chart?

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing the vote breakdown isn't essential for anyone on SO. In fact the site actively discourages discussing voting. Note how in the description of the [comment everywhere privilege](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)  tell you to not leave comments saying *+1 great answer!* or *-1 bad answer*. Or look at how poorly [requests](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4725/enforcing-mandatory-comment-when-downvoting) to require comments on downvoting are received.

Pretty much the only intended use of viewing the voting breakdown is to satisfy an idle curiosity. As a result it's gated behind 1000 reputation as a nice minor reward for sticking around for a while. This is hopefully high enough that users are socialized to not remark on how others vote before being exposed to more information about how people voted.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a good question, but I've had that privilege's so long that I don't remember not having it.
My guess; Maybe it's just so that they have something to reward lower rep users with, before you eventually get the actually useful privileges?

1000 might feel high, and it's a nice milestone, but if you're active it doesn't take that long to get.
It deserves a reward, but that rep you're still relatively new, and so possibly too soon for something like being able to edit questions or access the review queues.

Again, just my guess, but it kind of makes sense.

Edit: I tried to find the list of privileges and their rep requirements, but 5 minutes of looking didn't turn it up, and again I don't remember when I got each of them. It's possible that my theory wouldn't make any sense if I actually saw the list.

Comment: The list of privileges is [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: @sphennings hmm, yeah, I don't know why vote counts would be above review queues, but cool

Comment: I've always interpreted it as review queues are an essential part of this site functioning properly, while viewing vote breakdown isn't. Reviewing users first posts is a good introduction to the review process.  Seeing vote breakdown isn't essential to the site functioning properly so it's held back as a nice reward for people who've stuck around for a bit longer.